# Why don't my extensions show up in Banshee?

Tags: banshee

+++ Note: The behavior detailed in this question might actually be a bug. Awaiting comment from developers in [Bug 748461](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/banshee/+bug/748461).

---

I installed Banshee along with the community extensions pack. When I opened the program the first time, I got a long list of extensions to chose from, for example the Zeitgeist data logger.

The second time I started Banshee only half of that list was still showing up! I tried to deinstall Banshee completely by going to Synaptic and selecting "Completely remove Banshee". To my surprise, however, when I then reinstalled Banshee all settings were still there. The extensions list also stayed the same.

What can I do to access all the other extensions?

To make clear how it looks like, here are two screenshots:

---

The installed package
[image: Installed package]

This list looks rather empty for such a huge amount of extensions....
[image: Incomplete list of extensions]

Comment: Can it be that this is a bug?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using, and which version of Banshee did you install?

Comment: Please close, as indeed this was just a bug!

Comment: it might be a good idea to post your findings as an answer and then accept it. That's probably better than just closing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular problem was simply a bug. It has been fixed and should not occur anymore. If it does, please comment here!

Answer (score 1):

Once you've installed Banshee and the Community Extensions, you can control which extensions are active in Banshee through Edit > Preferences > Extensions (tab).

The Last.fm Shuffle Modes extension -- I think that's the one you're looking for -- should be listed there.  If you turn it on, it won't add an entry to Banshee's sidebar, though.  Instead, you can use it to generate songs from within the Play Queue by choosing "Fill by Similar Artists" or "Fill by Your Top Artists" (options that are only available if you've turned on the Last.fm Shuffle Modes extension).

If you've installed an extension through Synaptic or the Ubuntu Software Center and it isn't showing up in Banshee's extension list, I'd file a bug against the [Banshee package in Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/banshee).  If the extension is showing up in the list and the box next to it is checked, but it doesn't seem to be active in Banshee, I'd file a bug against [the upstream Banshee project](http://banshee.fm/contribute/file-bugs/).

Comment: The latter paragraph of your post is what I'm talking about :). I update my question to make it more clear.